# column header and row not aligning using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I am trying to use bootstrap styles to display a grid style. For some reason my column header and body aren't aligning. Could somebody tell me what the problem could be. I have also tried applying styling. I need to basically show Header for the first div which has class class="col-md-12.  I then need to style the body div which has class div class="row your-body" . At the moment your-body us just dummy has no style defined. Need help.

```
<div class="grid-container container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1">
        CompanyName
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        ContactName
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        ContactTitle
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        Address
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        City
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        Region
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        PostalCode
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        Country
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        Phone
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        Fax
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row your-body">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <ng-template let-customer let-customerIdx="index" ngFor [ngForOf]="customers">
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <span>{{customer.CompanyName}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <span>{{customer.ContactName}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <span>{{customer.ContactTitle}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <span>{{customer.Address}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <span>{{customer.City}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <span>{{customer.Region}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <span>{{customer.PostalCode}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <span>{{customer.Country}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <span>{{customer.Phone}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <span>{{customer.Fax}}</span>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**style.scss**

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    padding: 10px;
  }
```

Expection the UI to look

[image]

Comment: If you can turn this into a running example it would be a lot easier to debug, guess is your organization of the col and row are a bit out of wack, typically you have container > row > col, and if you need nested then in the col you have again container > row > col, also curious if you are able to move to bootstrap 4 or if this is a bigger project already using bootstrap 3 throughout, if using 4 is an option it might be worth solving there instead

Comment: bootstrap 4 is fine. I just have to display it as a table with header and details below

Comment: Could you suggest me a link where i could create simulation

Comment: Here you go http://cssdeck.com/labs/pqmesreg

Comment: Do you have a drawing of the layout you're trying to accomplish or can you describe in some more detail what's wrong?

Comment: I have attached a sketch to the post

Comment: Please bear in mind the image is tilted . I basically need the headers on the top and records below. The headers need to be distinctive

Answer (score 0):

This is a more 'valid' version of the layout code using bootstraps grid system:

```
<div class="outer-container container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
          CompanyName
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          ContactName
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          ContactTitle
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          Address
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          City
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          Region
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          PostalCode
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          Country
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          Phone
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
          Fax
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <span>121</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <span>232</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <span>3434</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <span>343</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <span>3434</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <span>3434</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <span>3434</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <span>34343</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <span>454545</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <span>3434</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cupnh1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

^^ for running example with a little nicer online editor IMO

Comment: I saw your stackblitz but didnt see any difference. I have attached a sketch to the post

Comment: Check out the order of row and col and container there shouldn't be  a row directly in a col.  Also check mobile vs desktop view since this is using md classes it will use the medium breakpoint to go from row display to column.. if you never want the responsive change use xs

Comment: @Tom apologies just updated think I still had your code in my clipboard when I thought I copied from stackblitz where I updated the code, I added it here.  Still you'd want `col-xs-1` if you want the columns to remain in that configuration down to small screen sizes otherwise with bootstrap 4+ you can just use `col` in a `row` if you are okay with the columns flexing to the content